# spring boot application on jboss not running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I have following maven configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <name>project-domain</name>
        <start-class>com.wearable.service.WearableServiceApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons.logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is my application class

```
package com.project.service;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Slf4j
public class ProjectServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static Class<ProjectServiceApplication> app = WearableServiceApplication.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
        SpringApplication.run(app, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(app);
    }
}
```

What I am expecting is that when i build this war and deploy it on jboss, I should see "-------------------" message in console, but i don't see any of this. neither i am seeing any error there.

The main issue i am having is that my *scheduler* isn't working. The scheduler class is in `com.project.service.scheduler` package. And here is the code. I am not concerned about `main`/`config` method but i want to know why scheduler isn't working.

```
@Component
public class DataScheduler {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 500, initialDelay = 500)
    public void scheduler() {
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }
}
```

Here is my jboss output

```
/Users/username/Documents/dev/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/standalone.sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper /private/var/folders/17/v3pnl0n532q_fvg8_8m3t2d00000gn/T/classpath0.tmp com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 63982 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss71Agent
=========================================================================
[2016-08-26 01:02:44,939] Artifact project-service:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.

Detected server admin port: 9990
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
Detected server http port: 8080

  JBOSS_HOME: /Users/username/Documents/dev/wildfly-9.0.2.Final

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

01:02:44,922 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
01:02:45,091 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
01:02:45,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) starting
01:02:45,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
01:02:45,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
01:02:45,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found fitbit-rest-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called fitbit-rest-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.dodeploy
01:02:45,855 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
01:02:45,870 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
01:02:45,876 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
01:02:45,903 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
01:02:45,903 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
01:02:45,907 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
01:02:45,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
01:02:45,921 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
01:02:45,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
01:02:45,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
01:02:45,954 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
01:02:45,963 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
01:02:45,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
01:02:45,969 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
01:02:45,969 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
01:02:45,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.5.Final)
01:02:45,995 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
01:02:46,070 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
01:02:46,070 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
01:02:46,135 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path /Users/username/Documents/dev/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/welcome-content
01:02:46,157 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
01:02:46,172 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
01:02:46,220 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080
01:02:46,315 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
01:02:46,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/username/Documents/dev/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments
01:02:46,473 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
01:02:46,592 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
01:02:46,593 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
01:02:46,593 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) started in 1915ms - Started 203 of 379 services (210 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Connected to server
[2016-08-26 01:02:46,954] Artifact project-service:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
01:02:47,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "project-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "project-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
01:02:47,826 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
01:02:47,827 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
01:02:47,958 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) 2 Spring WebApplicationInitiusernamezers detected on classpath
01:02:48,496 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) 
01:02:48,496 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   .   ____          _            __ _ _
01:02:48,496 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
01:02:48,497 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
01:02:48,497 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
01:02:48,497 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
01:02:48,497 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
01:02:48,498 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)
01:02:48,498 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) 
01:02:48,544 INFO  [com.project.service.ProjectServiceApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Starting ProjectServiceApplication on muhammads-macbook-pro.local with PID 34679 (started by username in /Users/username/Documents/dev/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin)
01:02:48,544 INFO  [com.project.service.ProjectServiceApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) The following profiles are active: dev
01:02:48,565 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7f63a29f: startup date [Fri Aug 26 01:02:48 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
01:02:48,995 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
01:02:49,008 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
01:02:49,008 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 443 ms
01:02:49,325 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
01:02:49,326 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
01:02:49,327 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
01:02:49,327 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
01:02:49,327 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
01:02:49,327 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
01:02:49,502 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7f63a29f: startup date [Fri Aug 26 01:02:48 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
01:02:49,547 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
01:02:49,548 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
01:02:49,564 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
01:02:49,564 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
01:02:49,585 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
01:02:49,698 INFO  [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
01:02:49,711 INFO  [com.project.service.ProjectServiceApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Started ProjectServiceApplication in 1.674 seconds (JVM running for 5.123)
01:02:49,747 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2 20150729-1131 for context '/project-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT'
01:02:50,659 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /project-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT
01:02:50,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "project-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "project-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
[2016-08-26 01:02:50,681] Artifact project-service:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-08-26 01:02:50,681] Artifact project-service:war: Deploy took 3,727 milliseconds
```

Comment: What's the solution you had got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` method isn't called when a Spring Boot application is packaged as a war and deployed to an app server. The `configure` method that you have shown above is called instead.

Comment: See my updated question. My main issue was that my scheduler wasn't working and while debugging i figured that `main` method isn't being called. I have put the code of scheduelr as well ... see what i am missing here